# Copying a file from an FTP server using an absolute path in PowerShell/WebClient

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, webclient

Am trying to copy a file from HP-UX to my Windows machine using PowerShell script.

Please find my script below.

```
$File = "d:\copiedfile.txt"
$ftp = "ftp://my_Unix_Domain_name/tmp/sourceFile.txt"
"ftp url: $ftp"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
"Downloading $File..."
$webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $File)
```

Am able to connected via FTP but, files not copied to my destination directory.

I'm getting an error:

> The remote server return ed an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Not sure, what is wrong in it.

I'm able to download the file using command-line `ftp`:

```
ftp> get /tmp/text.sh
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /tmp/test.sh (71 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 76 bytes received in 0.00Seconds 76000.00Kbytes/sec.
ftp>
```

Comment: You get some error for sure. What is it? + Can you download the same file using any standalone (even GUI) FTP client? Show us its log file.

Comment: Am getting this error `Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server return ed an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no acces)."`. But when am trying to get this file manually using `ftp` am able to get this file from remote location without any issues.

Comment: Again, show us the log file (or output) of the `ftp`! + Add the information (including the error message) to your question. Do not post important information in comments.

Comment: Am new to PowerShell., i not really sure how to log it. I will check for code to log it and then i will share it.

Comment: Log/output of `ftp`, not PowerShell.

Comment: am not seeing any log information for this script `C:\inetpub\logs` this path is empty.

Comment: When you run your commands or script with `ftp`, it displays some output. We want to see that.

Comment: am getting the attached screenshot message while am running the script. But., am able to copy the file from remote while am doing FTP manually from command line.

Comment: We know!! For the **5th time**: Show us the output of *"doing FTP manually from command line"*

Comment: output screenshot attached from "doing FTP manually from command line"

Comment: What does `get tmp/test.sh` (without leading slash) do?

Comment: Next time, post output as a text, not as an image!

Comment: No, without leading slash its giving `"550 tmp/text.sh: No such file or directory."`

Comment: Thankyou Soo much @MartinPrikryl .. I understood the problem., Thanks a lot

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - sorry to bother you a lot., as i was new to powershell. Now, am able to copy file via script too. But when i open in Notepad++ its format is proper. When i open the file in Notepad., all the contents are in single line itself., Do i need to do anything special for that formatting..??

Comment: I've posted, what I believe is a solution to your question. If it helped you, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: And post a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET implementation of FTP (`WebClient` or `FtpWebRequest`) do not consider the slash between hostname and file path to be a part of the file path.

So if you need to use an absolute path to a file (like `/tmp/sourceFile.txt`) in the URL, you have to add yet another slash:

```
$ftp = "ftp://my_Unix_Domain_name//tmp/sourceFile.txt"
```